# Parsing CSV with AWK to Produce HTML Output

Tags: awk, csv, html

I have a data file with rows of comma-separated fields like this:

```
United Kingdom, GB, +44
```

and I want to produce the following output for each line in the file:

```html
<option value="GB">United Kingdom +44</option>
```

I got as far as follows with awk, but after adding the angle brackets I am getting mangled output:

```c
BEGIN{FS=",";}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    print "<option value=\"" $2 "\">";                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

}
```

Answer (score 4):

awk's `printf` function can be easier to use when it comes to embedded quotes.

```
awk -F, '{printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s %s</option>\n", $2, $1, $3)}'
```

The problem with that is that you also have whitespace between each field. We can use the `gsub` function to trim each field.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"", $2); printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s %s</option>\n", $2, $1, $3)}'
```

Or what's easier is to change our field separator:
    awk -F' *, *' '{printf("%s %s\n", $2, $1, $3)}'

If you need to trim multiple fields then it might be better to use a loop or a function (depending on the situation). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985528/how-can-i-trim-white-space-from-a-variable-in-awk for more info.

Comment: I don't get the correct output with this. The "</option>" at the end does not appear at the end of each line. It only appears on the last line e.g. `</option>alue="+260">Zambia ZM
<option value="+263">Zimbabwe ZW</option>
`

Comment: @M.K. looks like your csv has CRLF line delimiters, convert to unix first with `dos2unix`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
awk -F "," '{print "<option value="$2">United Kingdom "$3"</option>"}' filename| sed 's/GB/"&"/g'
```

output

```
<option value= "GB">United Kingdom  +44</option>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this hardcodes (in the `sed` statement) the `GB` value in column 2; shouldn't it surround the option value no matter what it is?